# Per second rate values for a metric are coming different for prometheus and datadog

Tags: rate, datadog

I am very new to the monitoring of microservices using prometheus and datadog. I am trying to monitor the rate of event callback requests per second using PromQL queries and datadog queries but when i compared the values from both the tools, they came out to be very different. I want to know if the two values need to be same. If yes, then how do i write my queries to obtain the correct values

PromQL query

```
sum by (service)(rate(service_event_callback_processing_seconds_count[1m]))
```

Datadog query(json file)

```
{
  "viz": "timeseries",
  "requests": [
    {
      "q": "per_second(avg:prod.service_event_callback_processing_seconds.count{$service,team:callai})",
      "type": "line",
      "style": {
        "palette": "dog_classic",
        "type": "solid",
        "width": "normal"
      },
      "aggregator": "avg",
      "conditional_formats": []
    }
  ],
  "autoscale": true
}
```

Please tell me how can i make the two queries equivalent?